# How to show success message if there is no empty field after form submission in php

Tags: php

I have made an html form and validate it with php or more precisely part of validation (just check rquired field)
    Here is the html codes:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Registration Form</h3><br>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name : * </label><span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your name here">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username : * </label><span class="error"><?php echo $usernameErr; ?></span>
                    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your username here">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password : * </label><span class="error"><?php echo $passwordErr; ?></span>
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Type password here">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="rpassword">Retype Password : * </label><span class="error"><?php echo $rpasswordErr; ?></span>
                    <input id="rpassword" type="password" name="rpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Retype password here">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email : * </label><span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your email here">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Phone No : * </label><span class="error"><?php echo $phoneErr; ?></span>
                    <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your phone here">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dob">Date of Birth : * </label><span class="error"><?php echo $dobErr; ?></span>
                    <input id="dob" type="date" name="dob" class="form-control">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Select A Country : * </label><span class="error"><?php echo $countryErr; ?></span>
                    <input id="country" type="text" name="country" class="form-control not-me">

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender">Please Select Your Gender : *</label><span class="error"><?php echo $genderErr; ?></span>
                    <div class="form-control gender">
                        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender">
                        <label for="male" class="exclude">Male</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender">
                        <label for="female" class="exclude">Female</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="custom-btn" value="Submit" name="reg-form">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the php code to check if any of the field is empty:

```
<?php
    $nameErr = $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $rpasswordErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $dobErr = $countryErr = $genderErr = "";
    $name = $username = $password = $rpassword = $email = $phone = $dob = $country = $gender = "";

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
           $nameErr = " This field is required";
        }
        else {
           $name = $_POST["name"];
        }
        if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
           $usernameErr = " You must enter a username";
        }
        else {
           $username = $_POST["username"];
        }
        if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
           $passwordErr = " You must type a strong password";
        }
        else {
           $password = $_POST["password"];
        }
        if (empty($_POST["rpassword"])) {
           $rpasswordErr = " Your password didn't match";
        }
        else {
           $rpassword = $_POST["rpassword"];
        }
        if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
           $emailErr = " This is not a valid email address";
        }
        else {
           $email = $_POST["email"];
        }
        if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
           $phoneErr = " Please enter your contact number";
        }
        else {
           $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        }
        if (empty($_POST["dob"])) {
           $dobErr = " You must fill your Date of Birth";
        }
        else {
           $dob = $_POST["dob"];
        }
        if (empty($_POST["country"])) {
           $countryErr = " You didn't select a country";
        }
        else {
           $country = $_POST["country"];
        }
        if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
           $genderErr = " You can not leave this field empty";
        }
        else {
           $gender = $_POST["gender"];
        }
    }
?>
```

Now I simply want to show a success message after submission the form if there is no empty field.
N.B: This is my first php work.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

simplest solution would be to use simple flag variable, proof of concept using your code:

```
<?php
    $isFullyFilled = true; //flag 

    $nameErr = $usernameErr = $passwordErr = $rpasswordErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = $dobErr = $countryErr = $genderErr = "";
    $name = $username = $password = $rpassword = $email = $phone = $dob = $country = $gender = "";

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
           $nameErr = " This field is required";

           $isFullyFilled = false; //this is line which changes flag
        }
        else {
           $name = $_POST["name"];
        }
    .... //many other ifs modified like that
    if($isFullyFilled){
         showMessage("Form is fully filled");
    }
```

Comment: It shows Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function showMessage()

Comment: @JahangirHossain it was example, you need to define this function or do whatever you want, inner body of if is going to be called if every field in request is filled

Comment: Got it. Thanks @stetoc.

Answer (score 0):

add the following lines to the bottom of your php code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("the form has been completed")';
echo '</script>';
```